# Slow CakePHP form input

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, optimization

I'm creating some quite complex forms (much input, mostly checkboxes) with CakePHP. The problem is that it's quite slow : around 1ms / input, so around 1sec for 1000 inputs.

I'm using the CakePHP function `$this->Form->input(...);`

It there a way to faster the creation of these inputs ?

Thanks.

Comment: Not using objects, and creating simple tags.

Comment: use a better server - than you won't notice the time difference.

Comment: @mark : i'm using my developpement server which have a I7 processor and 8 GB of RAM. Seems to be good enough.

Comment: well, I never had a problem - even with huge forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML helper in CakePHP not fast. Use clear html if you want speed.

Also, you can try disable debugging and enable cache, but it's not very effective.